# NestJS SuperTest Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, nestjs, supertest

I want to save some data out of a body and use it with the next request in my tests. I'm doing a post request and get back an id. This id I want to use to fetch data in other test.

My code looks like this:

```js
it('/auth/register (POST)', async () => {
   const test = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/api/auth/register')
      .send({username: "Zoe"})
      .expect(201)
   token = test.body.token
})
```

The token is getting set and the code runs, however my jest test won't stop with and I'll get the error:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

I know that I can do forceExit but I want to do it clean and understand the problem.

When I do the jest return method, it's working.. However there Idk how to store the body somewhere..

```js
it('/auth/register (POST)', () => {
   request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/api/auth/register')
      .send({username: "Zoe"})
      .expect(201)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by closing the database connection when the application is shutting down

````
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { DatabaseModule } from './database/database.module';
import { FormsModule } from './forms/forms.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    FormsModule, 
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {
  onApplicationShutdown(){
    getConnection().close();
  }
}

```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using TypeORM. To debug you can try to set the flag
`--detectOpenHandles`.

like so:

```
jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json --detectOpenHandles
```

or

```
npm run test:e2e --detectOpenHandles
```

Then it can be related to the connection to your database or redis. For example, I use TypeORM and what helped me to solve the issue was:

// my.e2e-spec.ts

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
...

describe('MyController (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let connection: DataSource;

  beforeEach(async () => {
  ...
    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    connection = moduleFixture.get<DataSource>(DataSource);
    await app.init();
  });

  
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.destroy(); // <- this
    await app.close(); // <- and that
  });
});
```